# How do I find running Traces in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

Is there an easy way to determine what traces have been set up by `sp_trace_create` on SQL Server 2000? How about for SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012, or 2014?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**SQL Server 2005** (onwards):

```
    SELECT * FROM sys.traces
```

**SQL Server 2000** :

```
    USE msdb
    SELECT * FROM fn_trace_getinfo(default);
```

Ref: [`fn_trace_getinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173875.aspx)

Column descriptions for `sys.traces` DMV can be found here: [`sys.traces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-traces-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but a precisation. On a SQL 2000 server you must use msdb database. Es:

```
USE msdb
SELECT * FROM :: fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

Comment: This should be just a comment in the accepted answer, and not an aswer on itself. And "presisation" is not a word ;)

Comment: Sorry @RicardoC, I was just a beginner on stackoverflow :-)