# SQL SERVER - TRACEWRITE - How to find out why it would be slow?

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

I have been looking at the performance of one of our testing environments and the **TRACEWRITE** is at the top, these waits seems a bit long **1918.8 ms** which to seems rather slow?

I am running sp_BlitzFirst to give me these details.

```
exec sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1
```

[image]

I am happy with the other wait stats(I know how to make better) but unsure were to go with the TRACEWRITE wait, is this bad and if so what should I look at, to make it faster?

After the comments we can see we get this, which seems to be a rowset trace whatever that is!?

[image]

This would seem to be SQL Sentry which is used by the DBA's. Is 2 seconds acceptable for SQL Sentry?

Comment: someone leave traces running?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637013/how-do-i-find-running-traces-in-sql-server

Comment: `TRACEWRITE` indicates your trace is producing too much data for the profiler to receive. Either switch to XEvents (preferable) or narrow down how much data you are asking for.

Comment: @MitchWheat Yea memory is not enough, its 10GB which is something that I will get increased. so don't want to focus to much on that, but if you are saying that is related to the TRACEWRITE then great.

Comment: @Charlieface so are you saying something is profiling? I wasn't aware anything is profiling on this box(but don't know as only the dev on this and not a dba, who have extra permissions)! interesting. Ill take a look at what Mitch linked, thanks both

Comment: Again `TRACEWRITE` means it is waiting to write a trace, and if this is going direct to a client it could be waiting on the client machine.

Comment: @Andrew, run `SELECT * FROM sys.traces WHERE is_rowset = 1;` to see Profiler traces returning client results. There is also a default trace that's on by default but it is a file trace and will not cause `TRACEWRITE` waits.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks so we do see a rowset one, ive updated the question with the screenshot, sounds like it is Sentry that the DBA's use. That raises the question is 2 second wait time ok?

Comment: Shouldn't Sentry be using Extended events? Does it need to be updated perhaps?